# How can I put a new timeline chart for d3 on bl-ocks.org

Tags: d3.js, timeline, gist

I have created a new timeline chart for d3 that I want to put on bl.ocks.org
(GitHub Gist: https://gist.github.com/rengel-de/5603464).

My gist contains an 'index.html' file. Alle the required files are in the same gist.
Following the instructions on http://bl.ocks.org/, I added the 'bl.ocks.org' button to my browser 
(Chrome). But when I click this button on the Gist page, nothing happens.

So how can I put this chart on bl.ocks.org?

Answer (score 2):

Just add your gist's username and ID to the end of the bl.ocks URL, like this: http://bl.ocks.org/rengel-de/5603464.

Comment: Thank you! That was easy. I supposed that the 'bl.ocks.org' button would handle this.

Comment: Still, if I click on the 'bl.ocks.org' button of another gist (i.e. https://gist.github.com/mbostock/5577023) the button works as expected; the graph is shown. So what's the diffenrence?

Comment: You are right, the blocks button doesn't work on your gist. It's curious that it works when I fork it: https://gist.github.com/biovisualize/5609750 Maybe the regex doesn't handle the hyphen in your github name? https://github.com/mbostock/bl.ocks.org/blob/master/chrome/bl.ocks.chrome/blocks.js